# How to pass a field value from a parent node to its entity referenced children nodes when saving the parent node form

Tags: 8, forms

Drupal 8

Here is the scenario

I have a Company > Department > Employee… in that hierarchy.

Companies are already created previously.

On the Department node add form, there is an entity reference field to reference a Company. On that same Department node form, there is another Entity Reference field that leverages Inline Entity Form to add + reference Employee nodes on the fly. These Employee nodes also have a Company entity reference field.

The goal is to pass the Company field value from the Department node to the referenced Employee nodes when the Department form is saved.

I figure this may be accomplished with the Business rules module, and/or a hook form alter. Tried both without any traction. Any tips?

Comment: Is it neccessary to **save** the Company info into Employee entities or would just showing what Company the Emloyee belongs to on their page would be enough?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is necessary to save the Company info directly into Employee entities. There are some complex display and view filter outputs that require it.

Comment: Example... Employees can be created outside of Departments. And I need an Employee view output to be filterable by Company. The filter would then need to leverage the Company field in both the Department and Employee content type (instead of just the Employee content type). This would complicate things long term.

Comment: I expected the necessity to come from something else, like specific company policy, or site performance. You can use Views and Content View modes to show referenced information, without it being saved on the entity item that is related to it.

Comment: I hear you... combining a referenced field and non-referenced field into the same views filter is the ultimate challenge though. Any ideas here? For long term scalability, my above request still seems like the ideal solution.

Comment: That's a very common request. When you add the Relationship for the ER field into Views you unlock more Fields and Filters, they become available on the regular Add lists. You can also chain Relationships... Search for answers for sibling ER Views and you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks @prkos

Comment: @prkos - The chained relationships still don't make much sense to me. Don't see how to combine the same fields from different referenced nodes into a single view list, then into a single filter. I think this applies to another one of my questions as well -> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300279/combine-photos-from-parent-node-and-referenced-nodes-into-a-single-list-for-sli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_update/8.2.x) and [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x).

```
// Top of .module
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function MYMODULE_node_update(NodeInterface $node) {
  _MYMODULE_set_department_employee_company($node);
}

function MYMODULE_node_insert(NodeInterface $node) {
  _MYMODULE_set_department_employee_company($node);
}

function _MYMODULE_set_department_employee_company(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'department') {
    $dept_company_id = $node->DEPARTMENT_COMPANY_FIELD->target_id;
    foreach ($node->DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE_FIELD->referencedEntities() as $employee) {
      // Only update the employee company if it's different.
      if ($employee->EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_FIELD->target_id !== $dept_company_id) {
        $employee->EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_FIELD->target_id = $dept_company_id;
        $employee->save();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll run into any issues when IEF saves the employees - I'm not sure if IEF saves entities before or after the parent node is saved.

Comment: @sonfid - Great solution. Works flawlessly. Thanks again!

Comment: Note: I'd always wrap field work with `$entity->hasField(MY_FIELD)` before trying to access them or set their values. I didn't here just to keep the code focused on the issue at hand.

Comment: @sonfid - So you'd wrap the "foreach" statement above with `if($node->hasField(DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE_FIELD)){}` that sound right?

Comment: I'd check `$node` before setting `$dept_company_id` and `$employee` before checkout the company field on it.

Comment: Gotcha... Thanks!