# How to get a dynamic delta token in a multi-value field via views

Tags: 8, tokens

Here’s the situation…

- I have a multi-value PHOTOS field in views. The image ALTs are all unique.
- These photos are output into a slideshow, and I’m building a custom caption for each slide (photo) by combining HTML and TOKENS.
- Unfortunately, I’m only able to grab specific Delta numbers within the token list… such as [node:field_photos:0:alt] or [node:field_photos:1:alt]. But this obviously only passes that single Delta image’s ALT to all of the multi-value images.

**It’s required that these images remain in the same multi-value row and NOT in their own individual rows.

Is there any way to define a dynamic Delta based on the actual image shown? Something like [node:field_photos:?:alt]

In Drupal 7, there was a Compound Token module, which seemed like it may work. But in Drupal 8, I haven’t been able to find anything close to a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't see any easy way to do that while keeping them in the same row. Have you considered allowing for one image per row (so you get correct alt even with Rewrite), and then use Grouping by node ID to gather them back together?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @prkos - So my photos setup is as you suggested on this issue https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/300279/combine-photos-from-parent-node-and-referenced-nodes-into-a-single-list-for-sli/300284?noredirect=1#comment382076_300284.

Comment: Continued from above... so I have a Department photos field, and an Employee ER field (as a custom view mode outputting a photo) combined in a slideshow. The multi-value is for the Department photos field. If I define these Department photos as "one image per row" each single Department image will also output ALL the Employee ER photos per row.

Comment: So maybe an alternative question/solution to this is how do I combine the Department photo field and the Employee ER field in a view so each image (from either the Department or Employee ER fields) takes up one single row.. without duplicates. This would solve my image Title issue. Any thoughts? Thanks for looking at this @prkos